# What is the DFA used for pattern searching?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, finite-automata, dfa

E.g. regex `go*d` is a pattern will match strings like `gd`, `god`, `good` ...

And you can imagine its DFA would be like a 3-state machine.

When it is used for pattern searching, e.g. given sentence `xxxxgodxxxxgoodxxx`, The DFA of `go*d` seems not going to work. Even character `x` is undefined in this 3-state DFA.

We can imagine a 4-state DFA with an additional "reset" state may work here. That is, when there is an undefined character met, go into this "reset" state.

The question is how does pattern searching tool achieve the searching purpose with a regex like `go*d`?

Comment: This sounds a lot like your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489338/difference-between-pattern-matching-and-pattern-searching-in-terms-of-dfa-regex.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth They are related. But this question is about the implementing strategy for a given searching regex. The previous question is about the general difference between searching and matching. Solving the previous one could help this one.

Answer (score 0):

given the trivial 3-state matcher

```
|start|---/g/---+->|S1|-->-+---/d/--->|accept|
                |          |
                +--<-/o/-<-+
```

you don't need a reset state but a catch-all reflexive transition on your start state labelled with `[^g]`. strictly following the dfa definition, you'd need `|Σ|-1` transitions each labelled with one alphabet character other than `g`. similarly transitions from `S1` to `start` labelled `[^g]`and from `S1`onto itself labelled `g` guarantee proper 'reset' after encountering prefixes of possible instantiations of the pattern. enhance the `accept` state similarly and you will catch all non-overlapping pattern instantiations (which are all instantiations for this particular pattern.

of course this quickly becomes much more complicated than in this toy example which is why the standard regex->nfa->dfa construction is usually employed.

another strategy would be to take your original dfa without enhancements and spawn a subprocess each time you leave the `start` state. the subprocess applies the same dfa as its parent applying it to the given sentence starting with the character that made the transition leave the start state fire.